# SQL query-ind out all the dates in which the revenue from a user was greater than the revenue from that user on on their first day

Tags: mysql, sql

my goal is to find out all the dates in which the revenue from a user was greater than the revenue from that user on on their first day.

For example for the user AAA, with the following data

```
user_id, date, revenues
AAA, 2018-01-01, 30
AAA, 2018-01-02, 28
AAA, 2018-01-04, 45
AAA, 2018-01-06, 55
```

the output should be

```
user_id, date, revenues
AAA, 2018-01-04, 45 
AAA, 2018-01-06, 55
```

what query should I write?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`first_value()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(revenue) over (partition by user_id order by date) as first_revenue
      from t
     ) t
where revenue > first_revenue
```

Comment: Another question in the same matter-----Labeling our top paying customers is an important and valuable task. However, if we label too few players, we will likely miss revenue opportunities, and if we label too many players we will not focus our efforts in the right place. How would you approach this data science challenge?

Comment: @ShiraVahav . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* not as *comments*.  However, that question sounds like something opinion based and it requires a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient it is but:

```
WITH first_revenue AS (
SELECT
    user_id,
    MIN(date),
    revenues
FROM
    users_revenue
GROUP BY
    user_id
    )
SELECT 
    users_revenue.user_id,
    users_revenue.date,
    users_revenue.revenues
FROM
    users_revenue LEFT JOIN first_revenue ON users_revenue.user_id = first_revenue.user_id
WHERE
    users_revenue.revenues > first_revenue.revenues
```

Comment: This is giving me a: `Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.r1.revenues' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: strange, it should work in MySQL..

Comment: No, see docs: "As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default."    ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by )

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation of: "find out all the dates in which the revenue from a user was greater than the revenue from that user on on their first day" to SQL.

```
select t.* 
from rev t 
where t.revenues>(select min(t2.revenues) 
                  from rev t2
                  where t2.user_id=t.user_id
                  group by t2.user_id
                  having `date`>min(`date`));
```